# Cannot get lambda code sample to compile

Tags: vb.net, syntax, lambda

I want to experiment with a simple bit of code found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff664617%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx

But I cannot get it to compile, I must be doing something wrong. About a third of the way down the page it gives a code sample like this:

> 'Usage exManager.Process(Function() method-name(param1, param2), _
>                      "Exception Policy Name")

But if I enter the following code:

```
Dim exManager As ExceptionManager
exManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance(Of ExceptionManager)()
exManager.Process(Function() TestSub(), "Exception Policy Name")
```

I get an error on the third line that says:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Process' can
>   be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Overridable Function Process(Of TResult)(action As System.Func(Of TResult), policyName As String) As TResult': Cannot
>   refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or
>   shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.
>
> 'Public Overridable Function Process(Of TResult)(action As System.Func(Of TResult), policyName As String) As TResult': Data
>   type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these
>   arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this
>   error.
>
> etc.

Even if I try to modify the lambda like this:

```
exManager.Process(Function() Dim A As Integer=6, "Exception Policy Name")
```

I get a similar error.

Any comments would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Note I am compiling for .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: Is the function holding the process manager code a shared subrotine?

Comment: @user1937198 actually it was, but I then put it in a non shared function and it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Process(Of TResult)` overload when you call `exManager.Process(Function() TestSub(), "Exception Policy Name")`.

The method is generic and expects and type argument (`TResult`), which in a lot of cases can be inferred by the compiler. Now the exception tells you that, in your case, the compiler can infer `TResult`.

I guess your `TestSub` is really a `Sub` and therefore has no return value which the compiler could use to infer `TResult`.

---

So use the non-generic `Process` method by either using `Sub` instead of `Function`

```
exManager.Process(Sub() TestSub(), "Exception Policy Name")
```

or simply use `AddressOf`:

```
exManager.Process(AddressOf TestSub, "Exception Policy Name")
```